# Create object that conform to protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create cell that i know, is conformable to specific protocol.

However, when i try to do :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell<ModelBinding> = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VacanciesCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        return cell
    }
```

I got an error. How to fix it?

Comment: you can make an extension to all tableview cell or that specific cell class and conform to that protocol

Comment: @Lu_ i really believe that there is an easier way

Comment: this is extremally easy way, how do you want to make anything easier than that, it conforms or not, that simple

Comment: let cell : ModelBinding = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VacanciesCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ModelBinding

Comment: Well, you didn't create object that conforms to protocol. You only casted your cell. If it doesn't conform, your app will crash.

Comment: @MaciejKozieł yes i know, but they always will conform :)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban So you have your solution ;) Other answers are correct one for question you've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subclass cell , which confirms the protocol that you want to use. Here i have created a **sample protocol** and **CustomCell** which **confirming** the protocol i have created.

**1. Sample protocol**

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func protocolMethod()

}
```

**2. Custom subClassed cell**

```
class CustomCell:UITableViewCell,MyProtocol {

    //Implementation of Protol method
    func protocolMethod() {

    }

}
```

**3. Use of that cell on tableview**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VacanciesCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell

    return cell
}
```